# Wahoo API Integration in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have integrated wahoo api in iOS. I need to get `WFHeartrateData` for `WFFitnessEquipmentConnection`.
But not able to test without real adaptor. Is there any way i can test using iPhone device or other way?

Please find the below work in progress code implementation:

- Add parameter `WF_SENSORTYPE_FITNESS_EQUIPMENT` for startDiscovery and  implement `WFFitnessEquipmentConnection` (FE-C).
- Create a new object for `WFFitnessEquipmentConnection` and make connection to sensor using below method:
- `requestSensorConnection:deviceParams withProximity:WF_PROXIMITY_RANGE_DISABLED error:&error`
- Tried to get the data `WFFitnessEquipmentData` and `WFFitnessEquipmentRawData` from fitness equipment connection.
- `WFFitnessEquipmentData* hrData = [self.fitnessEquipmentConnection getFitnessEquipmentData];`
- `WFFitnessEquipmentRawData* hrRawData = [self.fitnessEquipmentConnection getFitnessEquipmentRawData];`

Comment: What have you tried already?  Please post your work-in-progress implementation.

Comment: Hi @JAL I have updated my question with WIP code implementation. Please see the updated question.